# Find out where a variable is initialized

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a class with variable “test” in my project. I need to find out at which page of the project/solution this “test” get initialized. Do we have any short cut keys for this, other than Ctl+F and look for entire project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very similar to @George's answer, but I prefer a `Ctrl+Shift+F` (Find In Files). Does about the same thing as Find All References, but doesn't have to compile anything to do it.

As for specifically looking for the initialization, a find in files of `text:b*=` (making sure Use Regular expressions is on), would find any place where you assigned to text.

This is assuming you didn't mean `Ctrl+Shift+F` in your question.

Answer (score 7):

try F12. There are some great shortcut posters here, print one out for your wall

[Visual Studio 2010 Keybinding Posters](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13189)

Comment: awesome, F12 takes the cursor directly to the objects instantiation point

Comment: Not if you have other than cs files in your file.

Answer (score 4):

You can right-click it, then Find All References, looking for `= new`, or if you prefer, `Ctrl-K, R`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the below regex to find variable which are initialized.

**Example**

```
int var = 10;
(?:\w+\s+)([a-zA-Z])+\s(\=)
```